# How to get client machine's hostname or computer name in php

Tags: php

How can i get the clients machine name or hostname in php. is it possible to use any function or javascript?

i am using below code. but it's always showing server machine's hostname.

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo $ip;
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $hostname;
echo getenv('COMPUTERNAME');
```

Comment: Php has nothing to do with your computer's name

Comment: @Hanky Panky no way??

Comment: I'm pretty sure that information isn't sent with HTTP requests, only their IP address (which can be spoofed). You could maybe do a reverse DNS lookup, but that's only as reliable as the IP they send you. Do a `var_dump` of `$_SERVER` and you'll see what's available.

Comment: I don't understand: your `$ip` and `$hostname` attempts are correct and should give you the _client_ (not server) ident. In the other hand, as pointed by @RoshanBhumbra, this information is not totally reliable.

Comment: @cFreed: but it's only showing IP correctly but not showing hostname/machine name. can you please tell do we need to allow anything at client side?/

Comment: I don't be sure of what you mean _exactly_ by "hostname/machine name". In my experience, IP (if not spoofed) is a really _individual_ ident, while most of the time `gethostbyaddr()` returns a _general_ name which is fixed by the internet access provider and you never can expect more.

Answer (score -1):

Get computer name in PHP when your web is running on local server.

Solution is only useful if want to run web on local machine.

```
echo php_uname('n');
```

Get full computer info

```
echo php_uname()
```

Comment: This get's the *server's* information, not the requesting IP's.

Comment: @ceejayoz answer updated.